# Adding a point at given lat/long Australia - suspected CRS issues

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, latitude-longitude

I am hoping to add a geographical point to a layer in QGIS with a specific latitude and longitude value (from GPS.) I have had no success with a number of methods (trying to edit with Numerical Vertex Edit, and by uploading a csv.) My project is in CRS GDA 94 MGA zone 55, EPSG 28355. "On the fly" is selected. I used the same CRS for my data point when importing the CSV. X field is long, Y field is lat. However, the point is not placed in the right place - it goes off way distant from my other data points, I think in a geographical point that does not even exist on earth.

When I try to use the Numerical Vertex Edit method, I have found no combination of settings that give me the point data X and Y values in Lat Long - they all seem to be in meters.

I am not totally across the difference between CRS systems - but am usually fine by saving all layers and projects as GDA 94 zone 55.

Comment: What are the X, Y values? A small sample would give us a better idea. It's possible you have the wrong zone; Australia traverses Zone 49 to 56 (not counting Australian Antarctica Christmas Island, Norfolk Island and Pitcairn Island)

Answer (score 3):

Lat/long are usually in degrees, while MGA zone 55 is in meters.

So you have to add your point in a new WGS84 layer, then copy and paste it into your MGA zone 55 layer.

Note that QGIS expects the degrees in longitude-latitude order, and southern latitudes negative.